# error in calling hosted wcf service method (The service is offline or inaccessible)

Tags: wcf, iis, localhost

My WCF service is hosted on IIS. It was working fine but suddenly it has started giving following error when I test it via WCFTestClient.

**"Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service."**

I would thank a million time for the solution. This has become pain in the neck for me.

Thanks,
Rizwan Farooq

Comment: You're more likely to get a response if you provide more details about the service, and maybe your relevant config sections as well.

Comment: Thank you Tim for the response but I figured it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer guys. actually I recently installed URL rewriting module in iis 6.0. after that error started propagating. I uninstalled URL rewriting module in iis and everything started working like a charm. I am using iis 6.0.